# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have poured through all the questions with this title and I cannot find a solution that prevents this error.  What I've tried so far is to ensure I'm not confusing old and new redux api, I'm transpiling using babel so no typescript solutions apply, I've ensured I'm returning a function in the action in question, I've commented out my import or thunk to make sure it breaks and I've logged out thunk after importing it and I get a function back, and I've updated the devtools extension from the depricated version. No success.  Any help is MUCH appreciated.  Relevant code follows:

Store:

```
const redux = require('redux');
const {combineReducers, createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} = require('redux');
import {default as thunk} from 'redux-thunk';

const {nameReducer, hobbyReducer, movieReducer, mapReducer} = require('./../reducers/index');

export const configure = () => {

    const reducer = combineReducers({
        name: nameReducer,
        hobbies: hobbyReducer,
        movies: movieReducer,
        map: mapReducer
    });

    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

    const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));   

    return store;
};
```

Actions:

```
export let startLocationFetch = () => {type: 'START_LOCATION_FETCH'};

export let completeLocationFetch = (url) => {type: 'COMPLETE_LOCATION_FETCH', url};

export let fetchLocation = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(startLocationFetch());

    axios.get('http://ipinfo.io').then(function(res) {
        let loc = res.data.loc;
        let baseURL = 'http://maps.google.com?q=';

        dispatch(completeLocationFetch(baseURL + loc));
    });
};
```

Code where action is dispatched:

```
console.log('starting redux example');

const actions = require('./actions/index');
const store = require('./store/configureStore').configure();

let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    let state = store.getState();

    if(state.map.isFetching){
        document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    } else if(state.map.url){
        document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = '<a target=_blank href = "' + state.map.url + '">Location</a>';
    }
});



store.dispatch(actions.fetchLocation());
```

I am just learning React/Redux now (this is for a course) so I really maybe missing something obvious. If I've left out something pertinent, let me know. Thanks

Comment: You could also replace `import {default as thunk} from 'redux-thunk';` with `import thunk from 'redux-thunk';` When importing without curly braces, that default export is saved on the whatever name you chose there (in this case `thunk`).

Comment: @cfraser That's interesting.  In the [docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) it says "If you use Redux Thunk 2.x in CommonJS environment, don’t forget to add .default to your import"  As I am using 2.1 I assumed importing or requiring specifically with .default would be needed, but I just tried what you said with no error.  I wonder why it states it specifically but isn't needed.

Comment: It's because that isn't CommonJS, it's ES5. CommonJS would be using `var x = require ('something').default`.

Comment: yes, of course.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export let startLocationFetch = () => {type: 'START_LOCATION_FETCH'};
```

is not returning an object<strike>, but should rather result in a syntax error</strike>.

To directly return an object from an arrow function, you need to set brackets, or it will be interpreted as a block:

```
export let startLocationFetch = () => ({type: 'START_LOCATION_FETCH'});
```

---

**Edit:** Thanks to Nicholas for pointing out that is indeed *not* a syntax error.

Comment: `should rather result in a syntax error.` Remarkably, it's valid syntax! `type: ` gets interpreted as a label statement, and it's then followed by a string expression. How insidious....

Comment: Yes!  Thank you very much.  I'm thrilled it was something like this and not the redux/thunk part.

Answer (score 2):

```
export let startLocationFetch = () => {type: 'START_LOCATION_FETCH'};

export let completeLocationFetch = (url) => {type: 'COMPLETE_LOCATION_FETCH', url}
```

I'd think these lines are the problem. The short syntax for functions works well, but for returning an object, you should wrap it with parenthesis, like this:

```
export let startLocationFetch = () => ({type: 'START_LOCATION_FETCH'});

export let completeLocationFetch = (url) => ({type: 'COMPLETE_LOCATION_FETCH', url})
```

So the transpiler knows that what's next is a single argument that has to be returned, and not the function body.